# Join Match on JSON using JQ

Tags: json, bash, match, jq

I have two output files, and they have multiple repeating entries with the following structure:

`file1.json`

```json
{
 "value": [
    {
          "description": "foo bar",
          "id": "111111-0000-0000-1111-foobar",
    },
  ]
}
```

`file2.json`

```json
[
    {
        "businessPhones": [555-505-4321],
        "displayName": "Abc",
        "givenName": "abc",
        "id": "000000-1111-1111-0000-abcabc",
        "descriptionId": "111111-0000-0000-1111-foobar"
    },
]
```

My need is to match the value of `descriptionId` from *file2* found in *file1*; But want to produce a final out —even if it is *file3*, that replaces that key value in a way to ends up into something like this:

`file3.json`

```json
[
    {
        "businessPhone": [555-505-4321],
        "displayName": "Abc",
        "givenName": "abc",
        "id": "000000-1111-1111-0000-abcabc",
        "description": "foo bar"
    },
]
```

So far, I've been able to massage some data using Bash and JQ —but at odds on how I can then parse these together.

Comment: Your examples are not valid json...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making the obvious corrections in the files, the following invocation:

```
jq --argfile file1 file1.json -f program.jq file2.json
```

produces the desired result, where program.jq contains:

```
($file1 | INDEX(.value[]; .id) | map_values(.description)) as $dict
| map(.description = $dict[.descriptionId] | del(.descriptionId))
```

You could use moreutil's [sponge](/questions/tagged/sponge) to overwrite file2.json if you're confident that that's what you really want.

Comment: Thanks @peak, this worked beautifully and I was able to teak it for my intend.  On my final implementation though, I might prefer not to have a separate file. So I'm going to play with the syntax and see if I can avoid the `-f`